# How to detect and remove duplicates from List in XmlArray (when reading in)

Tags: c#, xml, list, duplicates, deserialization

This is one attribute of a larger XML object (expressed in C#):

```
[XmlArray]
public List<CustomAssignment> CustomAssignments
{
    get => _CustomAssignments; set { _CustomAssignments = value; }
}
private List<CustomAssignment> _CustomAssignments = new List<CustomAssignment>();
```

The `CustomAssignment` object is:

```
public class CustomAssignment
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Index
    {
        get => _Index; set => _Index = value;
    }
    private int _Index;
}
```

I have noticed that sometimes I have duplicates in the XML data. For example:

```
<CustomAssignments>
  <CustomAssignment Index="0" />
  <CustomAssignment Index="0" />
</CustomAssignments>
```

I now know why it has been happening, so I can prevent it in the future. But is there an easy way to delete this duplicates from my `List`?

Can this be acheived when the XML file is being serialized in?

Comment: Once you have the list you can use .Distinct() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-6.0 On the other hand preventing it while serializing is easy, you only have to control it on the XmlSerializer

Comment: in this case, Distinct() will not work as the type of CustomAssignment is a reference type. He can either use the below solution or make 'CustomAssignment' struct.

Comment: @J.Salas How with XmlSerlializer?

Comment: I suposse with your complex class you also have a personalized XmlSerializer (possibly generated by xsd.exe)
control duplicates there ( add a control of existing CustomAssignment Ids array and validate before adding) https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have a variable called '_data' that ts filled with your XML data.

you can easily do this:

```
_data = _data.GroupBy(x => x.Index).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```